# MS Azure PaaS Web App Service + Local Deployment

Tags: azure, architecture, blob, azure-sql-database, paas

My application is running on Azure PaaS (BLOB Storage, Azure SQL, Web App)
One of my clients requires having the sql database and storage account to be on his premises.
What is the best topography you would recommend? is there a way to replicate the BLOB storage in real-time? 
How can I assert high availability knowing that his SQL and his Storage are subject for failure?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't a 1:1 on-premise equivalent of either Azure blobs or Azure web apps.  Specifically for SQL DB, you can use SQL Server in it's place.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> One of my clients requires having the sql database and storage account
>   to be on his premises.

SQL Database is easy. It is just replacing the connection string.

Storage is tricky. You might be able to modify [local storage emulator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-emulator/#differences-between-the-storage-emulator-and-azure-storage), and allow access from outside, but I have never tried it.

*Your application will be quite slow, since it has to access SQL and Storage from on-premise. My thought will be to host it on-premise where all resources are there.*